# Button are not connected in loop, but the last one is

Tags: javascript

```js
function createTimer(countdownObject) {

    let id = countdownObject.Id
    let removeClass = "inline remove" //(isRemoveButtonsEnabled && "inline remove") || "inline remove hidden"

    document.getElementById("countdownList").innerHTML +=
        `
    <dt id = "` + id + `" class = "countdown">
    <h2 id = "` + id + `-title" class="title">Example Timer</h2>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-daysNum" class = "time inline"></h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-daysDesc" class = "time description inline">days</h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-hoursNum" class = "time inline"></h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-hoursDesc" class = "time description inline">hours</h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-minsNum" class = "time inline"></h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-minsDesc" class = "time description inline">minutes</h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-secsNum" class = "time inline"></h3>
    <h3 id = "` + id + `-secsDesc" class = "time description inline">seconds</h3>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" id = "` + id + `-remove" class="` + removeClass + `"></button>
    </dt>
    `

    const removeButton = document.getElementById(id + "-remove")

    console.log(removeButton)
    updateTimer(countdownObject)

    removeButton.onclick = function () {
        removeTimer(id)
    }()


}

function removeTimer(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < countdowns.length; i++) {
        if (countdowns[i].Id == id) {
            countdowns.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(id).remove()
    console.log(countdowns)
    saveCountdowns()
}
```

I'm trying to create this countdown widget. I'm running this function in a basic for loop and inputting a `countdownObject` with keys of `Name`, `End` and `Id`. There's a problem that only allows one of the buttons to work at a time (usually the last one created) and I have no idea why. The `removeTimer` function works perfectly, its just a problem of all the buttons not getting connected to the `onclick` event.

[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmSbP.gif)

Comment: can you share the function removeTimer() code

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans just added it!

Comment: i wouldn't modify an array while iterating thru it

Comment: when clicking on the other buttons, are they triggering?

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans none of the buttons fire the function when clicked, just the last bottom one, (as you can see on the visual link)

Comment: Maybe you are using the same Id for all the timers. Can you share code on how you are creating timers, or a piece of the countdowns array

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans I'm not using the same Ids, the Ids are created when the timer is created, and I've checked live in dev tools to make sure they are all different, and they are.